# Finding last box on horizontal line and adding .last to it in jQuery masonry

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, jquery-masonry

I am wanting to use 1140 responsive grid for the main layout of a web page and jquery masonry for the home page content section boxes.

I need to dynamically add .last to the last masonry box in a horizontal row as the page size changes.

Does anyone have any idea of how I might go about this or provide a url to a tutorial?

I have searched through the docs and google with no avail.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Can you add some code? A JSFiddle would be useful.

Comment: I'm going to need a little more information on this since I don't see how you can have specific "rows" in masonry. Columns are possible, though. So, you re-call masonry for the page on the window resize event and I'd have to look in the masonry documentation, but surely there is a way to signal that the last column is being filled and include a class insertion...